# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis --- Inner Query Execution

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select *  from USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS 
 where substr(log_date,1,9) in (
     select substr(log_date,1,9) 
       from USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS 
      where rownum <= 1 ORDER BY LOG_DATE DESC);
```

When I am executing above query I am getting below error.

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:   
*Action: 
Error at Line: 7 Column: 55
```

I tried to execute inner query it is executing but not sure why it is giving me error while executing whole query.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use order by in the inner query. 
try this:

```
select * from USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS 
where substr(log_date,1,9) in 
(select substr(log_date,1,9) from USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS where rownum <= 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra information was contained in the parentheses.
[ORA-00907](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00907_missing_right_parenthesis.htm)

You can use this query as your expectation

```
select *
  from USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
 where substr(log_date, 1, 9) in
       (select MAX(substr(log_date, 1, 9)) over(ORDER BY LOG_DATE desc)
          from USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS
         where rownum <= 1);
```